# Stacking Monad Transformers in scala

Tags: scala, haskell, monads, scalaz, monad-transformers

I'm trying to stack monad transfromers of `scalaz` in a haskell way:

```
statyReader :: (MonadReader Int m, MonadState Int m) => m Int
```

scala:

```
  def statyReader[F[_]](implicit r: MonadReader[F, Int], s: MonadState[F, Int]): F[Int] = for {
    counter <- s.get
    secret  <- r.ask
    _       <- s.put(counter + secret)
  } yield counter
```

It compiles with 1 implicit passed, but not with 2:

```
Error:(13, 18) value flatMap is not a member of type parameter F[Int]
    counter <- s.get
                 ^
Error:(14, 18) value flatMap is not a member of type parameter F[Int]
    secret  <- r.ask
                 ^
Error:(15, 21) value map is not a member of type parameter F[Unit]
    _       <- s.put(counter + secret)
                    ^
```

Why is this happening? My guess is that compiler is now confused which "monadic instance of `F[_]`" it should pick(both MonadReader and MonadState extend `Monad[F[_]`). Is this a right guess?

How to overcome this?

Comment: Minor point: In Haskell, I would not call this "stacking monad transformers" since I'd use that to refer to e.g. `StateT s (ReaderT r IO) a`. It is true, though, that in such stack we would have multiple type constraints, so it IS related.

Comment: I don't think the two implicit parameters are the problem, otherwise you would get the error "ambiguous implicit values" (see https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/issues/1110).

Comment: @devkat if I pass only 1 implicit, the thing works :)

Comment: Sorry, my comment was unfounded :) Interestingly it works when one parameter is explicit and the other one implicit; it doesn't work if both are either explicit or implicit.

Comment: Actually it works with 1 implicit and doesn't work with 1 explicit(e.g. `justReader[F[_]](r: MonadReader[F, Int])` vs `justReader[F[_]](implicit r: MonadReader[F, Int])`), so I'm completely lost now.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer, but maybe helps a bit.

I think you're right; it seems like the compiler can't unify the `F[_]` types of both parameters (I guess since it is a higher-kinded type with multiple possible instances and not a concrete type instance) to a monad type. Compilation works with separate parameter lists since type unification only happens within a parameter list. It can be further illustrated like this:

```scala
def statyReader[F[_]](implicit r: MonadReader[F, Int], s: MonadState[F, Int]): F[Int] =
  statyReader2(r, s)

def statyReader2[F[_]:Monad](r: MonadReader[F, Int], s: MonadState[F, Int]): F[Int] =
  for {
    counter <- s.get
    secret <- r.ask
    _ <- s.put(counter + secret)
  } yield counter

Error: ambiguous implicit values: both
value s of type scalaz.MonadState[F,Int] and
value r of type scalaz.MonadReader[F,Int]
match expected type scalaz.Monad[F]
```

Obviously, as a workaround you could use two parameter lists to choose which monad you want to use:

```scala
def statyReader[F[_]](implicit r: MonadReader[F, Int], s: MonadState[F, Int]): F[Int] =
  statyReader2(r)(s)

def statyReader2[F[_]](r: MonadReader[F, Int])(implicit s: MonadState[F, Int]): F[Int] =
  for {
    counter <- s.get
    secret <- r.ask
    _ <- s.put(counter + secret)
  } yield counter
```